# Как задебажить или проинтерпретировать код в webstorm

Tags: webstorm

Скачал ide webstorm, хочу программировать на javascript в этой ide, создаю файл .js в проекте, а стандартные jetbrains кнопки дебага и исполнения неактивны.

Comment: там слева от них кнопка настроить конфигурацию.

Comment: откройте меню, нажмите зеленый плюсик, выберите подходящий вариант, укажите настройки (для nodejs это например исполняемый файл, для кордовы - метод и платформа) и кнопки станут активны

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Эти кнопки становятся активными в случае, когда у вас есть Run конфигурация. Простейший способ ее создать - выбрать "`create '<file name>'`" в контекстном меню файла - в этом случае создастся Node.js run конфигурация, которая позволит исполнять и отлаживать Ваш js файл как Node.js приложение. Редактировать существующие конфигурации, а также создавать новые, Вы можете в диалоге `Run/Debug Configurations`, доступном из главного меню, `Run/Edit Configurations...`. Не забудьте нажать на `+` для создания новой конфигурации, не пытайтесь вместо этого редактировать конфигурации в секции Defaults - это всего лишь шаблоны для новых конфигураций, их редактирование не создает активных конфигураций

Comment: см. также https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Running+and+debugging+Node.js+application (запуск и отладка node.js), https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/WI/Starting+a+JavaScript+debug+session (отладка клиентских web приложений)

Comment: А если я собираюсь разрабатывать под node.js, то мне лучше каждый раз создавать node.js express app?

Comment: если вы не собираетесь использовать express, то - нет, зачем? Можно просто создавать empty project

Comment: После я так понял создавать конфигурацию node.js или запускать чем командную строку?

Comment: да, создавать конфигурацию, если Вы хотите запускать или отлаживать его из webstorm